# Pythonically create a string representation of object with python literals

Tags: python

I have an object that's constructor accepts `*kwargs` and sets them as atributes.

```
class Observable(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])
```

I want print to represent the object in the following way:

```
>>> obs = Observable(foo=1, bar=5, _bazz=12, name='Amok', props=('One', 'two'))
>>> print(x)
Observable(bar=5, foo=1, name='Amok', props=('One', 'two'))
```

I tried to add a custom `__repr__`:

```
class Observable(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

    def __repr__(self):
        atribs = [(atrib,  self.__dict__[atrib]) for atrib in self.__dict__.keys() if not '_' == atrib[0]]
        atrib_strs = []
        for atrib, val in atribs:
            atrib_strs.append('{}={}'.format(atrib, val))

        out_str = '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join(atrib_strs))
        return out_str
```

For the input above it prints:

```
Observable(foo=1, bar=5, name=Amok, props=('One', 'two'))
```

My concern is that I have `Amok` instead of `'Amok'`. 
I can add a type check for strings, but perhaps there is a way to get a correct string representation of any python type? Maybe a standard library function?

Comment: I haven't looked into the question but my ocd is killing me to see *pytonically* instead of *Pythonic or Pythonically*.

Comment: @s_vishnu thanks, fixed

Comment: HAHA fine mate. Wait i'll try  for a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish this would be to call every attribute's value's `__repr__()` via `repr()`. That way, each string representation is 
*guaranteed* to be displayed.

```
>>> class Observable(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

    def __repr__(self):
        atribs = [(atrib,  self.__dict__[atrib]) for atrib in self.__dict__.keys() if not '_' == atrib[0]]
        atrib_strs = []
        for atrib, val in atribs:
            atrib_strs.append('{}={}'.format(atrib, repr(val))) # add repr() call

        out_str = '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, ', '.join(atrib_strs))
        return out_str

>>> ob = Observable(foo=1, bar=5, _bazz=12, name='Amok', props=('One', 'two'))
>>> print(ob)
Observable(foo=1, name='Amok', props=('One', 'two'), bar=5)
>>>
```

Comment: how about not using `dict.keys`/getting value and use `dict.items`/`dict.iteritems` instead?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Because he doesn't want to include "private" variables in the representation. Although his code could be improved., I didn't really try much.